# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client (with next)

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, middleware

I am trying to make some database queries and check some data. If some conditions do not match, it should create an error and forward with next(err).

The problem is, it sends me the error as response, but it tries to go on. So I am getting an error in my node.js app.

```
Purchase.findAndCount({where: {fk_product: productId, fk_buyer: req.decoded.id}}).then((numPurchases) => {
    // product purchased?
    if (numPurchases.count < 1) {
        const errNotBought = new Error("you did not buy this product");
        errNotBought.status = 403;
        return next(errNotBought); // <--- it should break up here
    }
}).then(() => {
    res.send({status: true, data: 'product'}) // <-- stacktrace point this line
})
```

The error is: Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` returns only from the current callback function, it doesn't stop a promise chain in any way. You are looking for

```
Purchase.findAndCount({where: {fk_product: productId, fk_buyer: req.decoded.id}}).then(numPurchases => {
    // product purchased?
    if (numPurchases.count < 1) {
        const errNotBought = new Error("you did not buy this product");
        errNotBought.status = 403;
        next(errNotBought); // <--- it should break up here
    } else {
       res.send({status: true, data: 'product'});
    }
});
```

Comment: okay this could be a solution but i have an errorhandler, where i want to pass the error. This is why Im using next for this.

Comment: This solution *does* pass the error to the `next` error handler, doesn't it?

Comment: right! thank you. Another possible solution is: throw new Error();

Comment: Yes, `throw errNotBought` might be even more appropriate, as it lets you handle that error as well as errors from `findAndCount` in a trailing `.catch()` from which you could call `next`.